# How to get results in separate rows after joining two tables

Tags: sql-server, query

I have two tables say - Plans and Discounts. Below are the sample data in Plans table.

[image: Plans Table]

Below are the sample data in the Discounts table.

[image: Discounts Table]

These two tables are related using PlanName column. I am looking for a query in the most optimized way to get a resultset in such a way that a discount for a particular plan should come below the corresponding plans. Sample data below.

[image: Result Set]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t table(id int identity(1,1),PlanName varchar(50),Amount int
                 ,startdate Datetime,enddate Datetime)

insert into @t values('ABC',100,'2019-01-01','2019-12-31')
,('ABC',100,'2019-04-01','2019-11-30'),('XYZ',300,'2019-04-01','2019-11-30')

 DECLARE @d table(DiscountName varchar(50)
,PlanName varchar(50),Amount int,startdate Datetime,enddate Datetime)
    insert into @d values('ABC discount','ABC',20,'2019-01-01','2019-12-31')


    ;

    WITH CTE
    AS (
        SELECT *
            ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                ORDER BY PlanName
                ) RowNum
        FROM @t
        )
    --select * from CTE
    --return
    SELECT ordercol
        ,PlanName
        ,Amount
        ,startdate
        ,enddate
    FROM (
        SELECT cast(RowNum AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) ordercol
            ,PlanName
            ,Amount
            ,startdate
            ,enddate
        FROM CTE

        UNION ALL

        SELECT cast(RowNum AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) + 0.1
            ,d.DiscountName
            ,d.Amount
            ,d.startdate
            ,d.enddate
        FROM @d d
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT TOP 1 RowNum
            FROM CTE t
            WHERE d.PlanName = t.PlanName
            ) t
        ) t4
    ORDER BY t4.ordercol
```

In my script main idea is `Ordercol`, so depending upon your real data `Window Function` may or may not be require.

If I assume that your `REAL TABLE` design and data is as seen, then if you use `INNER JOIN` then it will give duplicate records.To eliminate duplicate records you do some thing like `Distinct` or use `Window Function` which will degrade the performance.

So `CROSS APPLY` will perform ok in this case.Or you can test yourself with million records.

If your table is `Normalize` then it will perform the `BEST`.

Keep PlaName and Discount Name both in seperate table and refer the respective ID.

```
DECLARE @P table(PlanId int identity(1,1),PlanName varchar(50))
insert into @P values ('ABC'),('XYZ')

DECLARE @t table(id int identity(1,1),PlanId int,Amount int,startdate Datetime,enddate Datetime)
insert into @t values(1,100,'2019-01-01','2019-12-31'),(1,100,'2019-04-01','2019-11-30')
,(2,300,'2019-04-01','2019-11-30')

-- One to one relation between Plan Table and discount table
DECLARE @d table( DiscountName varchar(50),PlanId int,Amount int,startdate Datetime,enddate Datetime)
insert into @d values('ABC discount',1,20,'2019-01-01','2019-12-31')
```

Notice : `DiscountName`  should be in separate table.
         Also, notice how `Planid` is populated in `Discount` Table ?

It is ok for all other queries and requirement.In this requirement also you do not need `Window Function` So naturally performance improve tremendously.

```
SELECT ordercol
    ,PlanName
    ,Amount
    ,startdate
    ,enddate
FROM (
    SELECT cast(t.PlanId AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) ordercol
        ,P.PlanName
        ,Amount
        ,startdate
        ,enddate
    FROM @t T
    inner join @P P on t.PlanId=p.PlanId
    UNION ALL

    SELECT cast(PlanId AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) + 0.1
        ,d.DiscountName
        ,d.Amount
        ,d.startdate
        ,d.enddate
    FROM @d d
    --CROSS APPLY (
    --  SELECT TOP 1 RowNum
    --  FROM CTE t
    --  WHERE d.PlanName = t.PlanName
    --  ) t
    ) t4
ORDER BY t4.ordercol
```

`Planid` should be `Clustered Index` in both table.

Comment: I tried this and it worked for me. Also , it worked for me when I tried with INNER JOIN instead of CROSS APPLY. Which is better in this case?.

Comment: @inDiscover, check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is not a join which combines tables horizontally, you need a union set operator to join them vertically.
In your images all tables are named 'table 1' so I changed one of them to 'table 2' to make the query valid.

```
SELECT PlanName AS ProductName, Amount, StartDate, EndDate
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT DiscountName, Amount, StartDate, EndDate
FROM Table2
ORDER BY ProductName;
```

HTH

Comment: This will just club data from two tables. Also , as i mentioned clearly in my question,  it will not show a discount for a particular plan under that particular plan as shown in the sample result set. Also we dont need to show all the discounts if PlanName in the discounts table does not exist in plan table. I have mentioned this also in my question.

Comment: Did you try it? The order by will make the data sort per your request. And you didn't mention anything about " we dont need to show all the discounts if PlanName in..."  see https://m.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow